# ANTLR4 TypeScript target tries to import JS files

Tags: typescript, antlr4

As per bug report requirement I'll ask:

When using ANTLR4 4.12.0 as the following:

```
$ antlr4 -package My -listener -visitor -Dlanguage=Typescript ./My.g4
```

With a new TypeScript target I get the following output in `MyParser.ts`:

```js
import MyListener from "./MyListener.js";
import MyVisitor from "./MyVisitor.js";
```

I found the same `.js` extensions in the following source code:
https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/resources/org/antlr/v4/tool/templates/codegen/TypeScript/TypeScript.stg#L28-L33

Both files don't exist since they are JS files, and TypeScript generates output.

Does this works as designed or is this a bug?

Comment: Working as expected; ES modules require you to include the file extension. Remember that your TypeScript code is compiled into JavaScript files. TypeScript does not change your import paths. That's why they must be `.js` extensions, so that they work when your code is compiled.

Comment: I'm using Deno as a JavaScript runtime. It doesn't have a compilation step that would produce any JS files out of TS files so that seems more like an assumption of such things that do exist in NodeJS for example.

I could figure out import map mapping that helps but felt a bit suboptimal.